# Spring Boot 3: Startup failure caused by Logback logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm in the process of upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7.2 to Spring Boot 3, but the application fails to start, throwing an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.RootLogLevelConfigurator does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void configure(ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext)' of interface ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator.
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:140)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:130)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:179)
    at com.ret.rft.WsApplication.main(WsApplication.java:49)
```

In my pom.xml i have these dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I am using below versions

1. Java 17
2. Spring boot 3.1.5
3. logback 1.4.11

Edit 1 -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 

<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>pro-ws</artifactId>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.some.thing</groupId>
        <artifactId>something-parent</artifactId>
        <version>23.0.0_FP_03</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <snippetsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets</snippetsDirectory>
         
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.some.thing-alt</groupId>
            <artifactId>something-graphql</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- 3rd Party -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220924</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud.dependencies}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>

        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.restdoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
            <version>${xmlschema.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-jexl</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.jexl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>${xmlbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgrapht-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jgrapht.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>${jsoup.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>${jexcelapi.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven.jakartaee}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven.jaxb.impl}</version>
        </dependency>
         


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>javax.xml.accessExternalSchema</name>
                                    <value>all</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.build.helper.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>
                                    ${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.maven.jaxb.xjc}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.maven.jakarta.activation.api}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.maven.jakarta.xml.bind-api}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.maven.jaxb.impl}</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
                 
                     
             
             
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Edit 2
[image]

Edit 3

In my project i found we used **logback-spring.xml** will it impact anything?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 

<configuration>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="clr" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wex" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wEx" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />

    <!--<property name="LOG_TEMP" value="/opt/tomcat"/>  -->
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_TEMP" source="tomcat.log.dir"
                    defaultValue="."/>
     

    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE" source="logging.file.max-size"
              defaultValue="10MB"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY" source="logging.file.max-history"
              defaultValue="20"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_FILE_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP" source="logging.file.total-size-cap"
              defaultValue="200MB"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_AUDIT_FILE" source="logging-audit.file"
              defaultValue="${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/logs/catalog_audit.log"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_AUDIT_FILE_MAX_SIZE" source="logging-audit.file.max-size"
              defaultValue="10MB"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_AUDIT_FILE_MAX_HISTORY" source="logging-audit.file.max-history"
              defaultValue="20"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_AUDIT_FILE_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP" source="logging-audit.file.total-size-cap"
              defaultValue="200MB"/>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_MESSAGING_FILE" source="logging-messaging.file"
                    defaultValue="${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/logs/catalog_messaging.log"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_MESSAGING_FILE_MAX_SIZE" source="logging-messaging.file.max-size"
                    defaultValue="10MB"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_MESSAGING_FILE_MAX_HISTORY" source="logging-messaging.file.max-history"
                    defaultValue="20"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_MESSAGING_FILE_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP" source="logging-messaging.file.total-size-cap"
                    defaultValue="200MB"/>


    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
     

    <appender name="AUDITFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_AUDIT_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_AUDIT_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${LOG_AUDIT_FILE_MAX_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${LOG_AUDIT_FILE_MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>${LOG_AUDIT_FILE_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP}</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} | %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="MESSAGINGFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_MESSAGING_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_MESSAGING_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${LOG_MESSAGING_FILE_MAX_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${LOG_MESSAGING_FILE_MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>${LOG_MESSAGING_FILE_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP}</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} | %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>${LOG_FILE_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP}</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
         
    </appender>
    

    <springProfile name="PRODUCTION">
         
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </root>
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="WARN"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils" level="WARN"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="WARN"></logger>
        <logger name="org.crsh.plugin" level="WARN"></logger>
        <logger name="org.crsh.ssh" level="WARN"></logger>
        <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version" level="WARN"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration" level="WARN"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="com.netflix" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="com.mattbertolini" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="com.comptel" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="springfox.documentation.spring" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="com.hazelcast.cluster" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.activemq" level="WARN"></logger>
        <logger name="org.ehcache" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx" additivity="false"></logger>
        <logger name="audit-log" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="AUDITFILE" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="MESSAGINGFILE" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="DEBUG">
        <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "dev" or "prod" profiles are active -->
        <root level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </root>
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.crsh.plugin" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.crsh.ssh" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="com.netflix" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="com.mattbertolini" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="com.comptel" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="springfox.documentation.spring" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="com.hazelcast.cluster" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.activemq" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.ehcache" level="DEBUG"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx" level="DEBUG" additivity="false"></logger>
        <logger name="audit-log" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="AUDITFILE" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="MESSAGINGFILE" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="INFO">
         
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </root>
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.crsh.plugin" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.crsh.ssh" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="com.netflix" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="com.mattbertolini" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="com.comptel" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="springfox.documentation.spring" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="com.hazelcast.cluster" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.activemq" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.ehcache" level="INFO"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx" level="INFO" additivity="false"></logger>
        <logger name="audit-log" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="AUDITFILE" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="MESSAGINGFILE" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>
    
    <springProfile name="WARNING">
         
        <root level="WARNING">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </root>
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.crsh.plugin" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.crsh.ssh" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="com.netflix" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="com.mattbertolini" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="com.comptel" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="springfox.documentation.spring" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="com.hazelcast.cluster" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.activemq" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.ehcache" level="WARNING"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx" level="WARNING" additivity="false"></logger>
        <logger name="audit-log" level="WARNING" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="AUDITFILE" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing" level="WARNING" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="MESSAGINGFILE" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="ERROR">
         
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="com.netflix" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="com.mattbertolini" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="com.comptel" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="springfox.documentation.spring" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="com.hazelcast.cluster" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.activemq" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="org.ehcache" level="ERROR"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx" level="ERROR" additivity="false"></logger>
        <logger name="audit-log" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="AUDITFILE" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="MESSAGINGFILE" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>
    
    <springProfile name="TRACE">
         
        <root level="TRACE">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </root>
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="TRACE"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase" level="TRACE"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="TRACE"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils" level="TRACE"></logger>
        <logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="TRACE"></logger>
        <logger name="org.crsh.plugin" level="TRACE"></logger>
        <logger name="org.crsh.ssh" level="TRACE"></logger>
        <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle" level="TRACE"></logger>
        <logger name="org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version" level="TRACE"></logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration" level="TRACE"></logger>
         
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx" level="TRACE" additivity="false"></logger>
        <logger name="audit-log" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="AUDITFILE" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="MESSAGINGFILE" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Remove those dependencies. You don't even need `spring-boot-starter-logging` all of these are already pulled in by Spring Boot automatically. Defining them again (espeically the `log4j-over-slf4j` one) can lead to issues.

Comment: Can you post your version of `RootLogLevelConfigurator`? Most likely you have multiple versions of logback in your classpath - ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator has undergone some changes recently

Comment: Can you please your full pom.xml?

Comment: @M.Deinum  I tried to run without those dependencies but i am getting same issue.

Comment: @AnishB. Added pom.xml file.